# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list In Velocity Template

Tags: javascript, velocity

This is the code I have in my Velocity file:

```
#foreach ($key in $googleCharts.keySet())
     data.addRow(String($key), parseInt( $googleCharts.get($key)));
 #end
```

Once I run this, I get the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

When I see it on the console of the browser, I see that it's throwing the error on the second line in the below code:

```
 data.addRow(String(Customers), parseInt( 51));
 data.addRow(String(Medidata Users), parseInt( 70));
 data.addRow(String(Anonymous), parseInt( 1104));
```

Any reason as to why it might be happening ?

Regards,
Alok

Comment: This syntax is very strange: `String(Medidata Users)` Surely the space between `Medidata` and `Users` needs to be escaped?

Comment: The exception says it all. Essentially your arguments list to a function has finished and so it expects the closing bracket. However it hasn't got it and got some other value instead.

Comment: Yes, the space was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String(Medidata Users)` code in the second line doesn't make sense as far as javascript is concerned. This is the cause of issue.

Javascript doesn't allow space like this.